# php - How to generate correct unixtimestamp for facebook api for scheduled posting on a wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, unix-timestamp

I've checked some previous questions in this subject but couldn't find a suitable solution for this .it seems very small problem , but strange one. The problem :

I've create a php script to post on a users facebook pages using facebook php sdk. It works correctly when I want to publish my post on page directly. But I'm incurring an error when I set "scheduled_publish_time" for that. The error :

> (#100) The specified scheduled publish time is invalid.

I think, I'm generating the unix timestamp correctly for this option.But can't find the problem . here is my code :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Americas/New_York');
$date = strtotime("now +10 minute");

//posts message on page statues
$msg_body = array(
  'message' => $userMessage,
  'published' => 'false',
  'scheduled_publish_time' => $date
);
```

I'll be thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a programmer but shouldn't you set your timezone to `America/New_York`?
Without the `s` in `Americas`, check [Supported timezones for America](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php).

And you might need to use parentheses to use the now function e.g. `now()`

Comment: The `now` in `strtotime("now +10 minute")` is **not** a function. `strtotime()` understands relative time formats, see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and then I looked at documentation on FB developer site

> The scheduled_publish_time parameter should be included when
>   publishing a Page post, and it should be a UNIX timestamp that is
>   between 10 minutes and 6 months from the time of publish.

Your date is not correct. You need to provide valid timestamp which is current time + at least 600s. Please be aware that because of latency it could be problem if you specify 600 and in time it arrives to Facebook it is +599 and post will not be published.

Other problem is how you are using date function.

If you prefer to use human readable syntax then use this

```
strtotime("+10 minutes")
```

but better

```
strtotime("+11 minutes")
```

or

```
time()+3610; //I have added 10s more to avoid problems with processing
```